# Can I safely write files to web-served directory at runtime?

Tags: file-io

I have a PHP script that runs outside of the Nginx process. It copies files into a web-accessible directory. What happens if Nginx tries to serve a file for an HTTP request at the exact moment my PHP script is overwriting that file?

This is running on CentOS Linux. Probably my question is not specific to PHP. If you are familiar with file I/O on Linux, please feel free to use more general terms, OS-level APIs, etc.

I haven't seen the problem, but it's a race condition and no amount of testing would prove it couldn't occur. If there is a problem (e.g. Nginx failing to read the file or serving a partially written file), how could I solve it?

Comment: Rewrite the file to a temporary file and then just rename it to the correct file name.

Comment: It wouldn't serve a partially written file as the writer would almost certainly have it locked. How often are you taking about here? If it's infrequent, I wouldn't worry. If it's frequent, I'd look at another solution... perhaps a db, or time stamp named files or something. Or what Benjamin said!

Comment: @Benjamin, okay I researched a bit and POSIX rename will be atomic and also overwrite an existing file. (I don't have to delete file first, which open me up for another race condition.) So your solution should work.

Comment: @ErikHermansen yes, the fact `rename` is atomic is why I suggested it in the first place. Know that there are exceptions to that rule though - for example. `rename` is not atomic usually under FUSE file systems.

Comment: @Benjamin, feel free to write in answer form instead of comments and I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the file to a temporary file and then just rename it to the correct file name. Rewrite is atomic unless you're using a strange file system like one in user space.